# Proper sql query in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have table like this:

```
Name   Result  
T1     fail  
T2     pass  
T3     pass  
T2     fail  
T4     fail  
T1     pass  
T4     fail
```

Now, I want to get a results like this:

```
Name   Result
T1     pass
T2     pass
T3     pass
T4     fail
```

I tried using query like this, but it does not work.

```
select (case when Result = "pass" then "pass" else "fail" end) as Final_verdict,    
Name from table_1 group by Name
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Is that the whole table structure? It doesn't look normalized at all.

Comment: @chelmertz: but thats how my table looks like. can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: You should add a way to find each row, by making it unique. One example would be to add a `tested_on` column storing `datetime` for when the test was written. Depending on if you let different users "write tests" (I'm assuming a lot here), you could add a `user_id` field. If you cannot add any of these, I would go with a plain `id`-column set as an auto incrementing primary key (INT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Try the following:

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Result) As Result
FROM table_1
GROUP BY Name
```

This should return `pass` whenever there is one passed record for a row, as `pass` is lexicographically after `fail`.

---

Use `else` instead of the second `then`, and use `end` at the end of the `case`.
You might also have to use single quotes.

```
select (case when Result = 'pass' then 'pass' then 'fail' end) as Final_verdict,
       Name
from table_1
```

What do you expect to happen when the same name has different results?

Comment: sorry for the typos. But I corrected the sql query. I used the same that you suggested, but does not return the results I want

Comment: Thank you very much. I though MAX can be used only for integers

Answer (score 0):

Not the most pretty way, but depending on what you want to happen:

You want fail when there is any fail:

```
select name, min(result) from table_ 1 group by name;
```

You want pass if there is any pass:

```
select name, max(result) from table_ 1 group by name;
```

Or did you only want the last result for each `Name` in the table?

Comment: Thank you. I got it now with @Peter Lang